# Reliable timers for always on/timed/off lamps

Tags: smart-home, domoticz

I have a ZWave light bulb and a ZWave 4-button wall switch, both connected to Domoticz installed on a Raspberry Pi.

I'd like the following scenarios :

- Button 1 : lamp on for 30 minutes
- Button 2 : lamp off
- Button 3 : lamp always on
- Button 4 : summon Cthulhu

Each buttons overrides the previous action (Button 3 -> Button 1 = on for 30 minutes)

Wiring and programming the buttons is easy, but now, how about the timer ? I'd like to avoid creating a homemade service because I'm afraid of messing with `init.d`.

I have 3 possibilities :

---

### Domoticz dummy switch

Domoticz allows to create a dummy switch which can change states after some time given in an interface :

[image: domoticz dummy switch]

**Pros**

- off-the-shelf timer!
- I can interact quite quickly between my wall switch and the lamp

**Cons**

- although Domoticz handles MQTT, there will be a lot of LUA script and "blocky" to interconnect devices
- time might not be easily configurable...

---

### `at` and `atq`

[`at`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uat.htm) is a linux command to plan an action in time, as simple as

```
at [when] < [what]
```

**Pros**

- multi-timer service
- easy to use and call

**Cons**

- at only gives an unique ID, unless parsing the planned command I can't give a name to the job (unless with a magic linux command...)
- therefore I need to code/implement a job matcher using a database

---

### Crontab

Crontab is a linux service to plan repetitive tasks. In my case it will be a simple

```
# check every minute
* * * * * /path/checktimer.sh
```

**Pros**

- Reliable time trigger

**Cons**

- Cannot manage seconds...
- Still forced to maintain somewhere a job matcher

---

To my question :

- **Did you have to manage timers like this kind?**
- Did I miss other more reliable/configurable solutions?
- Do you have a preference with on the solutions above?

Comment: Just use `sleep` or `usleep` to trigger the off?  Its the underlying function under at,  and you can the use `jobs` to handle background jobs (mainly to cancel a planned off if I understood properly)

Comment: `sleep` looks worse : you only pass a time and it returns nothing. Can you answer and give an example using `jobs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per request I'll try to give an example on how I would tackle it (with bash shell `jobs` handling):

Button 1:
When turning on a lamp X for 30 seconds and lamp Y for 5 minutes:

```
echo "Switch on lamp_x" && sleep 30s && echo "Switch off lamp_x" &
echo "Switch on lamp_y" && sleep 5m && echo "Switch off lamp_y" &
```

Due to process limitations, this has to be on two separate lines, the echo above should be replaced by actual commands obviously.

button 3:
You can then `kill` sleep to stop it and keep the light on by getting a job pid and killing it:

```
kill $(jobs -p %?lamp_y)
echo "Switch on lamp_y"
```

The fact the commands are chained by `&&` will prevent the command after `sleep` to run as sleep didn't exit properly.
This doesn't handle non existing job, which may cause kill to return an error, nothing bad should happen here.

Button 2:
Using the same method as button 3, but using the stop command and killing the jobs if any.

Button 4:

```
echo "Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn"
```

(sorry I've no idea what you wish here, set for completeness)

---

Details of implementations about `jobs`:

`jobs -p %?lamp_y` return the current pid `-p` of a job matching the jobspec `%?lamp_y` which means `lamp_y` may appear anywhere in the command line, choose carefully what to use here (but I bet you have a unique identifier for things or group of things you wish to control).

Comment: I'm not volunteering to test your implementation of button 4.

Comment: One liner killing job is perfect! Thank you! I BTW I tried your button 4 implementation and now all my lights are flashing and there is a creepy sound everywhere, great for a Halloween party!

Comment: Protip : start the command with `true taskid &&` so you can track easily your job ! Unfortunatly this doesn't work if PHP or another program calls the command because it will be launched as a subshell...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use an online service for this, you should be able to use https://www.stringify.com They support sequences and variables (and timers). I've not used their service in anger, but it looks like you should be able to use a timer to decrement a variable (which determines the remaining on time), and the various trigger events can force the variable to a new value.

They support IFTTT integration, so pretty much any endpoint can be linked in some way.

Answer (score 3):

I've found another way quite expensive yet working with external processes such as PHP's `system` : **screen**

First, install it :

```bash
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Then call your function

```bash
screen -dm -S taskid bash -c 'sleep 20 && command'
    -dm : detach process
    -S  : identify screen by name
```

To list your tasks

```bash
ls /var/run/screen/S-www-data (or S-anotheruser, warning it is user bound, or sudo it)
```

To kill it

```bash
screen -S taskid -X kill
    -S : identify screen by name
    -X : access the screen and perform this command
```